# how to fill boxes inside boxes with open cv

Tags: python, opencv

Ok, since no one is answering let me try and change my question,
how could one go about  trying to identify this boxes?

Picture where i want to detect

[image]

to get this:

Picture i want to get

[image]

im having trouble since there are white letters inside the box.(i think)
Can anyone provide a soluction?

I'm starting out with CV, doing a simple project to learn.
I'm trying to get boxes inside boxes and count them.
I'm detecting the edges and doing a Thresh binary inv.
I'm getting this, which i think is pretty good and i should be able to work with,

picture after processing

[image]

after i go on doing a detection of shapes, but i only find one box, te big one.

I'm to the point of thinking:
A)  the problem is that the boxes inside are not "completed"
B)  the lines are not a segment

But for what i read,  if it dectets the edges it should see it has 4, and detected as a rectangle.

Here is a code

```
thresh = cv2.threshold(edges, 177, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

cv2.imshow("Image", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
sd = ShapeDetector()
```

after i iterate thourg the edges and try to draw over them in green

And my shape dectector

```
class ShapeDetector:
def __init__(self):
    pass

def detect(self, c):
    print("ola")
    # initialize the shape name and approximate the contour
    shape = "unidentified"
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)

    if len(approx) == 4:
        # compute the bounding box of the contour and use the
        # bounding box to compute the aspect ratio
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        ar = w / float(h)
        print( "Found one!")
        shape = "rectangulo"

    return shape
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The buzz-killer tag is *" enter image description here"*. Alas, you get an upvote for "nice exercise during coffeebreak" (should be a tag).

Comment: Woops new to this, thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL (which retrieves only external contours) you should use something else such as cv2.RETR_LIST (simple list with all contours) or cv2.RETR_TREE (all contours in a hierarchy).

See https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html

EDIT:
RETR_TREE is more complex but gives you the information of what contours are inside other contours, so you can ignore some of them.

If you want perfect rectangles, you should draw the result of the boundingRect() instead of the original contour.

If you find overlapping rectangles, you can also add more conditions to eliminate them (w and h should be between a minimum and a maximum for example).

Comment: it kinda work, but now i have many lines detected.
and when drawn theys til dont add up to perfect rectangles.
How can i accomplish this? in the end i would live to have 3 variables.
Box1, box2, box3. each one defined by some coordinates